# Parse a yaml file in a for loop and create new yaml files - non-specific tag - Python

Tags: python, yaml

Hi guys I want to load a yaml file, parse it and create new yaml files for every non-specific tag (!Element)

I want so scarpe this the parts of every !Element in a new yaml file vor example

new_folder/element1/element1_config.yml

the content should only be:

```
    name: element1
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
      - '*setup'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1
```

My yaml looks like this (my original yml is really big and has more than 100 !ELements so for this question I used a shorter version):

```
elements:
  - !Element
    name: element1
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
      - '*setup'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1

  - !Element
    name: element2
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1

  - !Element
    name: element3
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
      - '*setup'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1
```

Do you have an idea how I can solve it?

What I have so far:

```
import yaml


with open ('elements.yml', 'r') as elements_file:
    elements_yml = yaml.load(elements_file)

elements= elements_yml["elements"]["!Element"]

for element in elements:
   os.makedirs(elements_yml["elements"]["!Element"]["name"])

   # create new yaml file with content of element
```

Comment: Do you care about the comment `# indirect related on`? Comments are generally thrown away by PyYAML so you cannot easily preserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process a YAML file's structure and do not care about the content, you do not need to construct native Python objects. Instead, use the node graph:

```py
import yaml, sys
from yaml.nodes import SequenceNode, MappingNode
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

input = """
elements:
  - !Element
    name: element1
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
      - '*setup'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1

  - !Element
    name: element2
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1

  - !Element
    name: element3
    gnc_script:
      - '*fcc_cores_1'
      - '*setup'
    relationship:
      - projectx
      - projectxy
      - projectxyt
      # indirect related on
      - projectxyz1
"""

node = yaml.compose(input)

visited = set()

def output(node):
  yaml.serialize(node, sys.stdout)
  sys.stdout.write("...\n")

def visit(node):
  if node in visited: return
  if node.tag == "!Element":
    node.tag = BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG
    output(node)
  visited.add(node)
  if isinstance(node, SequenceNode):
    for child in node.value:
      visit(child)
  elif isinstance(node, MappingNode):
    for k,v in node.value:
      visit(k); visit(v)

visit(node)
```

This outputs:

```yaml
name: element1
gnc_script:
- '*fcc_cores_1'
- '*setup'
relationship:
- projectx
- projectxy
- projectxyt
- projectxyz1
...
name: element2
gnc_script:
- '*fcc_cores_1'
relationship:
- projectx
- projectxy
- projectxyt
- projectxyz1
...
name: element3
gnc_script:
- '*fcc_cores_1'
- '*setup'
relationship:
- projectx
- projectxy
- projectxyt
- projectxyz1
...
```

This code includes its input and outputs to stdout for demonstration purposes; just rewrite `output(node)` to create the files you want and replace input with the file you want to process. For example, this would write them in separate files; requires an existing scalar value for the key `name` in the element:

```py
def output(node):
  name = next(x[1].value for x in node.value if x[0].value == "name")
  with open("{0}.yaml".format(name), "w") as f:
    yaml.serialize(node, f)
```

As you can see, comments in the input are not part of the output. This is because they are thrown away by PyYAML's parser. There's no easy way to fix this with PyYAML; you could try [ruamel](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) which tries to preserve comments but I don't know its API.

Comment: Hi, thats for your answer but if I try to put this output into 3 different yaml files, it does not work I get a strange syntax. Could u add the part where u create a yaml file vor every name and paste the content? 

If I do this I get such a weitd syntax like this: !!python/tuple
  - !!python/object:yaml.nodes.ScalarNode
    end_mark: !!python/object:yaml.error.Mark
      buffer:

And with the Unicode syntax :(  for example \n

Comment: @Shalomi90 Added code to create separate files, not sure what you did.

Comment: that's almost perfect. My only problem is now to get the "name" of each element. Yeah in this example it was element1 ,2 3 but in real its always something else. So I need to get them. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Shalomi90 You need to navigate the node structure to query the name. I updated the `output` function to do that.

Comment: Thank u very much it works!! I just thought about, can I do it simpler (read yaml file  with yaml.load) save the string and write the parts in new files. I tried this and it says could not determine a constructor for the tag !Element

Comment: @Shalomi90 You can register a custom constructor for the `!Element` tag to be able to use `load`. I used the compose API because it loses fewer information about the input: For example it knows whether some value was quoted or not and will keep it that way, while with `load` both quoted and non-quoted values tend to become strings and for those the dumper decides whether and how to quote them.